# Const data modification in C

Tags: c, constants

I have const data in my project and I want to change it without removing the const qualifier.

How can I do this using const cast in C?

Comment: You can't do that. It's essentially UB.

Comment: Show some code of your data and how you want to change it

Comment: It may not work, the compiler can have done whatever with the variable, it may not even exist anymore. So don’t, just remove the const.

Comment: I found const_cast in C++ and I am asking if there is similar way in C?

Answer (score 2):

If you declare something as `const` you assume that you will not change it. If you want to change something do not make it `const`. It is a very simple rule.

Any attempt of changing the `const` object is an Undefined Behaviour. So you should not have been doing it.

Answer (score 1):

You have not written any code, so it can be hard to guess exactly what you want. But assume you have this:

```
const int my_data;
```

It might be tempting to do this, but it is undefined behavior, do don't do it. It may work or not, but it's not reliable at all:

```
int *p = (int *)&my_data;
```

Something that might do the trick is something like this:

```
int my_data;
const int *my_interface = &my_data;
```

Then you have a read only interface to the data, but you can still modify it.

Comment: I do not see any sane reason of doing it exept of the function parameters.

Comment: @P__J__ I guess it could be somewhat motivated if you have a global data structure that should only be modified by certain functions but you still want to access the data. But yeah, there are most likely better ways to do it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change it, then it isn't *constant* and should not be declared with the `const` qualifier:

> **6.7.3 Type qualifiers**
> ...
> 6     If an attempt is made to modify an object defined with a const-qualified type through use
> of an lvalue with non-const-qualified type, **the behavior is undefined**. If an attempt is
> made to refer to an object defined with a volatile-qualified type through use of an lvalue
> with non-volatile-qualified type, the behavior is undefined.<sup>133)</sup>
>
> ---
>
> <sup>133) This applies to those objects that behave as if they were defined with qualified types, even if they are
> never actually defined as objects in the program (such as an object at a memory-mapped input/output
> address).</sup>

<sup>*[C 2011 Online Draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)*</sup>

Emphasis added.  If you declare something as `const` like

```
const int var = 100;
```

and then try to change it through a pointer like

```
int *p = (int *) &var;
*p = 200;
```

then it's not guaranteed to work for several reasons - for one thing, making an object `const` *may* result in it being stored in read-only memory:

> **6.7.3 Type qualifiers**
> ...
> 4     The properties associated with qualified types are meaningful only for expressions that
> are lvalues.<sup>132)</sup>
>
> ---
>
> <sup>132) The implementation may place a `const` object that is not `volatile` in a read-only region of
> storage. Moreover, the implementation need not allocate storage for such an object if its address is
> never used.</sup>

in which case the above operations would trigger a segmentation violation.  If the address of the object is never taken, there may be no storage reserved for it at all - the compiler may simply substitute the literal value in the code.

A better option may be to restrict access via an API - put the data in its own separate module and expose a getter and setter:

```
/**
 * data.h
 */
#ifndef DATA_H
#define DATA_H

int get_mydata( void );
void set_mydata( int val );

double get_myotherdata( void );
void set_myotherdata( double x );

#endif

/**
 * data.c
 */
static int my_data;
static double my_other_data;

int get_mydata( void ) { return my_data; }
void set_mydata( int val ) { my_data = val; }

double get_myotherdata( void ) { return my_other_data; }
void set_myotherdata( double val ) { my_other_data = val; }
```

This way you never access your data items directly, making it less likely they'd be accidentally changed.